# Form validation phonenumber input

Tags: javascript

I want to validate the phonenumber input field but for some reason when I click on submit It's not validating. I have built a funtion for that but still not working. Below the code. 
Any help would be very helpful. Thanks in advance

**Contactform**

```
    <script>
  function phonenumberValidation()
 {
   var a = document.getElementById("phone").value;
   if(a=="") {
     document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="verdomd";
     return false;
   }
 }
</script>
<div class="contact">
    <h3>Mail ons</h3>
    <p class="text-center text-danger"><%= message %></p>
    <form method="POST" action="send">
      <p>
        <label>Naam</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" required>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Organisatie</label>
        <input type="text" name="company">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required >
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Telefoonnummer</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="">
        <span id="message"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="full">
        <label>Bericht</label>
        <textarea name="messages" rows="5" required></textarea>
      </p>
      <p class="full">
        <button type="submit">Versturen</button>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "still not working": Please elaborate.

Comment: I see `function phonenumberValidation()`, but I do not see any code or markup which would call that function. Please [edit] your question to add that code.

Comment: Please don't use javascript on client side to validate input. Anything that comes from user is not to be trusted. It is a security issue.

Comment: What can you suggest  Jon?

Comment: @JonNezbit A first check on the client side is useful for faster feedback, then *also* validate it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add event listeners for your function. Also you are missing `id="messages"` as well as `a===""` not `a==""`.

Below is example of code reacting on change for field phone:

```js
document.getElementById("phone").addEventListener("change", phonenumberValidation);
function phonenumberValidation()
 {
   var a = document.getElementById("phone").value;
   console.log(a);
   if(a==="") {
     document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="verdomd";
     return false;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="contact">
    <h3>Mail ons</h3>
    <p class="text-center text-danger"><%= message %></p>
    <form method="POST" action="send">
      <p>
        <label>Naam</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" required>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Organisatie</label>
        <input type="text" name="company">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required >
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Telefoonnummer</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="">
        <span id="message"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="full">
        <label>Bericht</label>
        <textarea name="messages" id="messages" rows="5" required></textarea>
      </p>
      <p class="full">
        <button type="submit">Versturen</button>
      </p>
    </form>
```

And example of form being stooped on click submit:

```js
    document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
      var a = document.getElementById("phone").value;
       console.log(a);
       if(a==="") {
       event.preventDefault();
         document.getElementById("messages").value +="verdomd";
         return false;
       }
    });
```

```html
<div class="contact">
        <h3>Mail ons</h3>
        <p class="text-center text-danger"><%= message %></p>
        <form method="POST" action="send">
          <p>
            <label>Naam</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" required>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Organisatie</label>
            <input type="text" name="company">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" required >
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Telefoonnummer</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="">
            <span id="message"></span>
          </p>
          <p class="full">
            <label>Bericht</label>
            <textarea name="messages" id="messages" rows="5" required></textarea>
          </p>
          <p class="full">
            <button id="submit-btn">Versturen</button>
          </p>
        </form>
```